# Tkinter progressbar not working under Windows

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, scaling

I am writing an application that will be used under both Linux and Windows.

For the GUI I am using Tkinter, but I've got a problem when I try to run my program on Windows. On Linux, where I developed it, it works just fine.

I used a toplevel with a ttk progress bar to show the progress of loading data, before the program/GUI shows up. 
This progress bar is missing on Windows. It doesn't throw an error, it just seems to be not there. The place where it SHOULD be is transparent, so you can see the windows/desktop etc. behind the toplevel.

Any ideas why this occurs? Did anyone else had this problem?

Here's the code that calls the toplevel:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import platform
import time

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.init_progbar()
        self.prog_data()
        self.top.destroy()

    #initializing progress bar, may be used with self.top
    def init_progbar(self):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.top.frame = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.top.frame.grid()
        self.top.frame.progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.top.frame, \
            orient='horizontal', mode = 'determinate', length = '500')
        self.top.frame.progbar.grid()
        Window.center(self.top)

    #static method to center a toplevel window
    @staticmethod
    def center(toplevel, size=None):
        toplevel.update_idletasks()
        w = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth()
        h = toplevel.winfo_screenheight()
        if not size:
            size = tuple(int(_) for _ in toplevel.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        x = w/2 - size[0]/2
        y = h/2 - size[1]/2
        toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (x, y)))

    #dummy method - somethings done, then the value of the progress bar
    #is raised by 10
    def prog_data(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.top.frame.progbar.step(10)
            self.top.update_idletasks()

def main():
    window = Window()
    window.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

As I said earlier, this is running under Linux without any problem, it just doesn't work on Windows.

I tried it on two different Linux systems ( openSUSE and Ubuntu ) and on two different Computers running Windows, one Windows 7 and one Windows 10. Every time the same problem occurs - the progress bar is missing on Windows.

Comment: The first step should be to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will a) give you a deeper understanding of the problem (and possibly illuminate a solution), and b) help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: without actual working code we can't duplicate the problem, which makes it very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Well the code is there. I don't think the code where i gather data is necessary, there are just some lines that process data, then the line "self.top.frame.step(10)" follows. Any other code relative to the problem is in the question.

Comment: If we are to assume that this code faithfully illustrates what is going on, then the problem is that you are destroying the toplevel immediately after you create it, and before the event loop ever gets a chance to render it.

Comment: I edited it, so it may be clearer what's happening. I can just underline again, this whole thing is working as it's supposed to be on Linux - the only problem is that the progress bar just doesn't appear on Windows.

Comment: One of the versions of the code you posted had some windows-specific code branches. The current (as of this comment) version does not. Does your actual code have windows-specific code paths? If so,  have you tried commenting them out?

Comment: My actual code looks ( except from the prog_data method ) exactly like the above. Of course I checked the current version of the code i posted, and the problem occurs here - it works fine under Linux, but not under Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. The problem was that the execution under Windows and Linux seems to be a bit different.

Windows does not update the GUI until you go into mainloop in the above example. The handling of this matter is obviously different on Linux, ensuring the correct execution.

For clarity, I reworked the example code, so it may become clearer what needed to be changed. Check the comments for further explanation.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import platform
import time

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.init_progbar()
        self.prog_data()
        self.top.destroy()

    #initializing progress bar, may be used with self.top.
    def init_progbar(self):
        #The frame here was unnecessary.
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.top.progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.top, \
            orient='horizontal', mode = 'determinate', length = '500')
        self.top.progbar.grid()
        Window.center(self.top)

    #static method to center a toplevel window
    @staticmethod
    def center(toplevel, size=None):
        toplevel.update_idletasks()
        w = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth()
        h = toplevel.winfo_screenheight()
        if not size:
            size = tuple(int(_) for _ in toplevel.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        x = w/2 - size[0]/2
        y = h/2 - size[1]/2
        toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (x, y)))
        #This processes every pending geometry change and redraws the widget.
        self.update()

    #dummy method - somethings done, then the value of the progress bar
    #is raised by 10
    def prog_data(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.top.frame.progbar.step(10)
            #Updates the whole GUI every time some data gets processed.
            self.update()

def main():
    window = Window()
    window.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```